# How do I cast Object to a specific parameter in a converter?

Tags: java, jpa, casting

I have a multiple JPA converters like this example:

```
@Converter
public class CurrencyConverter4jpa
implements AttributeConverter<Currency, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn( Currency value ) {
        if ( value == null )
            return null;
        return value.getCurrencyCode();
    }
    @Override
    public Currency convertToEntityAttribute( String value ) {
        if ( value == null )
            return null;
        Currency cur = Currency.getInstance( value );
        return cur;
    }
}
```

Another one is converting a UUID to a 'binary(16)' and back. I store the instantiated converter in a field:

```
private Class<?> convClass = CurrencyConverter.class;
AttributeConverter<?,?> conv = converterClass.newInstance();
public void setConverter( Class<?> converterClass ) {
    this.convClass = converterClass;
    this.conv = converterClass.newInstance();
}

public Object getSQLField( ResultSet rs ) {
    Object value = null;
    if ( conv != null ) {
        value = conv.convertToEntityAttribute( resultSet.getObject( 4 ));
    ...
```

Using this converter with just a Java Object results in a compiler error. What I tried is something like:

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: The error is: The method convertToEntityAttribute(capture#10-of ?) in the type AttributeConverter<capture#9-of ?,capture#10-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: what do you mean "I store the instantiated converter in a field:" Post your class that uses the converter

Comment: I have adapted the class which uses the converter. It maps a database table column to a Java property. I hope the additional lines can help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the parameter for `.convertToEntityAttribute` is supposed to be `String`, and you are sending in an `Object`. Try replacing `resultSet.getObject` with `resultSet.getString`

Comment: Why is it supposed to be a string? You are right in this special case of my converter example. But I also have a converter for UUIDs and a couple of others. That's why I use "Object". Is it necessary to build a huge switch based on the column type?

Comment: Well, the method is declared to accept the parameter of type String ...
I figure, you'd need a switch statement (or some equivalent of it) either way, if you were to call different methods for different columns, wouldn't you?
Alternatively, you can change your method's parameter type to Object, and cast it to the expected type inside the function itself.